# Batch For Loop Splitting on Tab Delimiter

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to write a batch script that uses a for loop to read in lines from an input file. I want to split each line that is read in on a tab delimiter. The input file is formatted as shown below with a tab between sourcefile and version. There is also an endline character after version.

```
sourcefile1   version1
sourcefile2   version2
sourcefile3   version3
```

I am running the following batch file.

```
@echo off
 for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=\T^" %%a in (input_file.txt) do ( 
   echo a = %%a 
   echo b = %%b 
)
```

My output is as follows:

```
a = sourcefile1 version1
b =
a = sourcefile2 version2
b =
a = sourcefile3 version3
b =
```

My desired output is:

```
a = sourcefile1
b = version1
a = sourcefile2
b = version2
a = sourcefile3
b = version3
```

Any input on how I can achieve my desired output? Thank you

Comment: `delims=\T^` specifies three delimiter characters, the sequence `\T^` does not mean anything special in `cmd`. Simply remove the `delims=` option string, so it defaults to _space_ and _tab_; if the _space_ disturbs, you have to literally specify the _tab_ character. *N. B.:* To avoid having to directly place the _tab_ character into a batch file, I prefer to use `for /F "delims=" %%T in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo/0x09"') do set "_TAB=%%T"` to get it and further `%_TAB%` to use it…

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Cmd with tab completion turned off using `cmd /F:OFF` an then use `"tokens=3 delims=^T"`, here `^T` will be the tab literal.

Comment: turning off tab-completion only enables you to use the TAB key on the command line to produce a TAB (instead of default-behavior to complete filenames). Batch files usually are created with an editor, which has this behavior anyway, so your answer is missleading.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the delims options gave me my desired output

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-2" %%a in (input_file.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   echo %%b
)
```